# Hard to write multi-threaded integration tests with transactional support

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, transactions, specs2

Suppose this spec/test using [Specs2](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/):  (the concept is likely to be similar in Java, so I tagged the post as Java also)

```
"Given there are 2 meetings stored, when I retrieve all stored meetings, I should see 2 meetings" {
    createMeeting1()
    createMeeting2()

    val retrievedMeetings = Await.result(meetingQuery.all, Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) 
    retrieveMeetings must haveSize(2)
}
```

The `all` method definition is:

```
def all = Future[List[Meetings]] {
     // Returns the future while executing the DB request
}
```

The issue is that the result is not `2` but `0`.
Indeed, I noticed that the creations and retrieval don't happen in the same transaction (as one Spring transaction is created by Specs2 example and especially **per thread**).

More precisely, the reading transaction managing by the retrieval thread can't see the created meetings, since those ones belongs to the Spec transaction (using @Transactional on the spec method) and are not already committed.
So of course, the retrieval says: "there are no meetings !"

How should I handle this case?
**I think about making creations and retrieval sharing the same transaction**, even if I should take off the `@Transactional` on my Specs2 class, and handling them manually.

Should I create a `Future` initially, managing the meetings creations and then chaining it with the retrieval, the whole within the same thread?
If this mechanism is possible, may anyone post an example?

Of course, when I don't use any multithreading (without `Future`), the whole works as expected.

Note: I use a transaction in the main flow since I want to rollback my meetings at each end of Specs2 example.

Comment: I found this great article dealing with the issue:  http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/spring-pitfalls-transactional-tests.html